# Creating dynamic JLabels and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I am trying to create dynamic `JButton` and `JLabel` based on the number of URLs defined in the properties file.

What I have tried so far is:

```
AppResources.properties file

urls=http://google.com,http://stackoverflow.com,http://gmail.com
urlLabels=Internet Users,MPLS Users,Physical Access (Not Advised)
```

In my Java program I am reading the properties file and based on the `comma separator` splitting the string and now i need to generate the buttons and labels accordingly. Like the `first URL Label --> first URL as Button` and so on.

The way I have done this so far is:

```
String url = properties.getProperty("urls");
        String urlLabel = properties.getProperty("urlLabels");
        String[] jButton = url.split(",");
        String[] jLabel = urlLabel.split(",");


        for (int i = 0; i < jLabel.length; i++) {
        JLabel labels = new JLabel(jLabel[i]);
        panel.add(labels);
        for (int j = 0; j < jButton.length; j++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(jButton[j]);
            panel.add(button);
        }
        }
```

But it prints the button three times for a label. How to fix this? Also how to write the action listeners for these buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement action listeners for your buttons, you can simply create and add a new ActionListener while creating the button.

Example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jLabel.length; i++) {
    final String str = jLabel[i];
    JLabel labels = new JLabel(str);
    panel.add(labels);
    JButton button = new JButton(jButton[i]);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, str);
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inner loop (j based).